# Controller component react-hook-form got undefined (reading '_names') use jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hook-form

I try to test my custom component with Controller use jest

```
import { Controller , useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const Wrapper = () => {
    const methods = useForm()
    
    return (
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
          <Controller name="test" render={()=> <div/>}/>
      <FormProvider>
    )
}

jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => {
  const reactHookForm = jest.requireActual('react-hook-form');
  return {
    ...reactHookForm,
    useForm: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('example test',() => {
    it('test Controller Component',() => {
      const {container} = render(<Wrapper/>)
      expect(container).toBeInDocument()
    })
})
```

but got error like this when run test

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_names')
```

can someone explain to me ?